# Doctrine2: several object properties from one db field

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Is it possible to have several representations of one db field in Doctrine2 entity?

Live example:
I have encrypted object in database field. I've created special data type for decrypting that field on-the-fly. Now I need to have both encrypted and decrypted values in entity after selecting from db.

I've tried to solve that problem this way:

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="EncryptedData", name="data")
 */
private $data;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="data")
 */
private $encryptedData;
```

But doctrine generates error about duplicate fields.

Comment: What @nikita2206 proposes seems pretty much like what you want. Maybe you can use a [LifecycleEvents][1] to encrypt/decrypt the data other than that, you just need a property for the encrypted data which will be persisted and another class property for the unencrypted/decrypted data which is accessible via getter/setter and which will not be stored in the database.

  [1]: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/event_listeners_subscribers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet in database should be one field?
You need something like this:

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="EncryptedData", name="data")
 */
private $data;

private $encryptedData;

public function getData()
{
    return $this->data;
}

public function getEncryptedData()
{
    if ($this->encryptedData === null) {
        // do with that data whatever you need
        $this->encryptedData = processSomehow($this->data);
    }

    return $this->encryptedData;
}
```

Comment: `type="EncryptedData"` is not a valid Doctrine type also I think you meant to place the Annotation on `$encryptedData`.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, when I commented on the question directly, but by then it was too late to edit this comment. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that it is the best one describing a good solution. But I did it other way. I created one more entity for holding both encrypted and decrypted data and it is filled in EncryptedData class. So I have an object instance in $model->data.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the duplicate fields error because both fields are called "data" in your annotations. If you  want to have both fields in your database table try something like this:

```
/**
 * @var array
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="data")
 */
private $data;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", name="encrypteddata")
 */
private $encryptedData;
```

That said, storing sensitive unencrypted data in your database is not a good idea security-wise.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I have the only one column in DB that stores encrypted data.

Comment: In that case try nikita2206's solution. It should work for you.